# Script using jquery not working on ie toggleclass

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

This is my script

```
   $(window).on('load', function(){
    $('#parceiro-campeao img').tilt({
        scale: 1.2
    });


    /* botao ver todas as agencias */
    $('.ver-todas').on('click', function(){

        $containerAgencias = $('.container-agencias');
        $containerAgencias.toggleClass('exibindo-todas');


        if( $containerAgencias.hasClass('exibindo-todas') ){
            $(this).text('VER MENOS');
        }
        else{
            $(this).text('VER TODAS');
        }
    });
```

When I click the button with the class ver-todas it is supposed to show more images but its not working. Do you have any solutions? Also, when I click the button the class exibindo-todas is not even being displayed.
I'm using jquery 3.1.1

Comment: If you could edit with those html elements you spoke about, it would help to test. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Guys the problem was that i was calling a script on the head of the page, which is not supported by ie. I made a condition using php and solved the problem. Thank you <3